# Using equations (with symbols) in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to use equations in the matplotlib legend, it is showing me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParseFatalException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py in parse(self, s, fonts_object, fontsize, dpi)
   2580         try:
-> 2581             result = self._expression.parseString(s)
   2582         except ParseBaseException as err:

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseString(self, instring, parseAll)
   1954                     exc.__traceback__ = self._trim_traceback(exc.__traceback__)
-> 1955                 raise exc
   1956         else:

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py in unknown_symbol(self, s, loc, toks)
   2751         c = toks[0]
-> 2752         raise ParseFatalException(s, loc, "Unknown symbol: %s" % c)
   2753 

ParseFatalException: Unknown symbol: \DeltaG, found '\'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

-----[snip]-----

ValueError: 
\DeltaG_0 = 1
^
Unknown symbol: \DeltaG, found '\'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

What is the issue in the following code ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
lines = plt.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10), range(10), np.random.randn(10), range(10), np.random.randn(10))
plt.legend([r'$\DeltaG_0 = 1$',r'$\DeltaG_0=2$',r'$\DeltaG_0=3$'])

plt.show()
```

I need the upper case Delta symbol($\Delta$) in my legend.

Also, is there anyway to reduce the following expression to something like 3*[np.random.randn(10), range(10)] ??

```
plt.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10), range(10), np.random.randn(10), range(10), np.random.randn(10))
```

Comment: `$\DeltaG_0$` isn't valid latex. `$\Delta G_0$` is and works as you intend

Comment: Also including the error is a best practice when asking questions. Since you don't understand it, including it would open up the opportunity for people to explain it to you. I'll add the error in for you

Comment: @PaulH Thank you for your help. Yes, I shall keep that in mind.

Comment: as for your second question (which belong in a different question), the docstring of `np.random.randn` states that you can pass as many dimensions to it as  you want. So all your need to do is `lines = plt.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10, 3))`

Answer (score 1):

You can actually put delta directly in your code. Matplotlib supports it. You can also just use a for loop for your second question.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
for _ in range(3):
    plt.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10))
plt.legend([r'$ΔG_0 = 1$',r'$ΔG_0=2$',r'$ΔG_0=3$'])

plt.show()
```